# ¿Cómo hacer un Join en la misma tabla?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Quiero que en mi tabla Ajax me muestre los datos, pero en la columna de *juridico* me muestra solamente el id. ¿Cómo puedo que en vez de que me muestre el id en número, me muestre el nombre de ese id relacionado?

Controlador.

```
public function index(){

    $direcciones = DB::table('direccion')
    ->leftjoin('direccion', 'direccion.fk_direccion_id', '=', 'direccion.id')
    ->select('direccion.id','direccion.nombre','direccion.responsable','direccion.extension','direccion.correo','direccion.jef_dir','direccion.nombre as nombreJur')
    ->get();

    return view('vendor.adminlte.direccion', [
        'direcciones' => $direcciones
    ]);

}
```

Modelo.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Direccion extends Model
  {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'direccion';
    protected $fillable ['nombre','responsable','extension','correo','jef_dir','fk_direccion_id','created_at','updated_at' ];}
```

Vista *blade.php*

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="direccion">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre de la Dirección</th>
                <th>Nombre del Responsable</th>
                <th>Extensión</th>
                <th>Correo</th>
                <th>Dirección(1) o Jefactura(2)</th>
                <th>Jefactura</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($direcciones as $direct)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$direct->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$direct->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$direct->responsable}}</td>
                <td>{{$direct->extension}}</td>
                <td>{{$direct->correo}}</td>
                <td>{{$direct->jef_dir}}</td>
                <td>{{$direct->nombreJur}}</td>
                <td>
```

Migración.

```
public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('direccion', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('responsable');
        $table->string('extension');
        $table->string('correo');
        $table->string('jef_dir');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('fk_direccion_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('fk_direccion_id')->references('id')->on('direccion');
      });
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto me arroja este error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'direccion' (SQL: select `direccion`.`id`, `direccion`.`nombre`, `direccion`.`responsable`, `direccion`.`extension`, `direccion`.`correo`, `direccion`.`jef_dir`, `direccion`.`nombre` as `nombreJur` from `direccion` left join `direccion` on `direccion`.`fk_direccion_id` = `direccion`.`id`)

Comment: Para hacer JOIN en la misma tabla debes usar alias, como bien indica @porloscerrosΨ , pero me extraña mucho esto: `'direccion.fk_direccion_id', '=', 'direccion.id'` ¿qué es  `fk_direccion_id` exactamente? ¿No es esa columna redundante? Puede que tu problema sea más grave: de diseño en las tablas, o de comprensión sobre cómo funciona join ¿?

Comment: La fk_direccion_id es la foreign key de la tabla de dirección, asi es como se declaro en  la migracion, si entiendo el diseño de las tablas, lo que aun no entiendo si mediante una consulta de sql puedo conseguir lo que quiero, y lo que dices del alias no lo eh intentado

Comment: Pero la llave foránea estaría en otra tabla, no en la misma tabla, lo cual no tendría sentido.

Comment: si en esa parte lo entiendo, voy a corregir ese detalle, gracias.